# Why does make_unique of a struct fail when containing an std::promise as member?

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr

I wrote the struct `MyParam` so that it could instantiate using any number of parameters, which in this case are an `int` and a `bool`. For encapsulation reasons, I would like for `MyParams` to contain its own `promise` so it can report when it is done doing something. But when I add the statement to the struct, it fails. As a global, though, it works fine. Here is the code:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>
#include <future>

//std::promise< bool > donePromise; // OK: if at global level, then make_unique error goes away

template< typename... ArgsT >
struct MyParams
{
  MyParams( ArgsT... args ) : rvalRefs { std::forward_as_tuple( args... ) } {}

  std::tuple< ArgsT... > rvalRefs;
  std::promise< bool > donePromise; // causes make_unique to fail when donePromise is a member of MyParams
};

int main()
{
  int num { 33 };
  bool tf { false };
  MyParams< int, bool > myParams( num, tf ); // OK
  auto myParamsUniquePtr = std::make_unique< MyParams< int, bool > >( myParams );

  std::future< bool > doneFuture = myParams.donePromise.get_future(); // OK: when donePromise is a global

  return 0;
}
```

> ```
> error C2280: 'MyParams<int,bool>::MyParams(const MyParams<int,bool> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
> ```

What am I missing with regards to the `promise` statement as a member?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::promise`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/promise) is not copy-constructible.

```
std::make_unique< MyParams< int, bool > >( myParams )
```

Above, `make_unique` is attempting to copy construct a `MyParams< int, bool >` which is ill-formed due to the presence of the `promise` data member. You can get the code to compile if you move construct instead.

```
std::make_unique< MyParams< int, bool > >( std::move(myParams) )
```